# store the state of a toggle button using an existing shred preference file in the project

Tags: android

I am working on a project which was already developed by someone. In this project shared preferences had already been used in many places, in may classes.I want to use the same shared preference file to store the state of a toggle button on my new activity( i have created a new java file and introduced a new activity). I am not sure how can i store the state of a toggle button which exist on new activity by using the already defined shared preference file. I am also not aware where this file has been created and initiated.

Comment: You need to look in the project wherever the sharedpreferences are being used and then see how it's implemented and then do the same with your class. Usually it will be a key value pair to store in shared preferences.

Answer (score 0):

To get the shared preferences try this in your `onCreate()`.

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
```

and you can save items in this file as Key,Value pairs:

example:

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = app_preferences.edit();
        editor.putString("weight", "180lbs");
```